# Scrolling not working in the mobile version

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm working on a Javascript project. I created a div with an overflow and I would scroll that div using the mouse only (without the bar). I followed [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/MP2cg/) working example both on the browser and both on the mobile versions. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
        ...  divs, boxes generated by jQuery ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
margin-left: 45px;
position: absolute;
width: 900px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#scroller {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
margin: 0px auto;
overflow: auto; 
}
```

Now the problem is that this works on the browser but does not in the mobile (no scrolling).

EDIT:

```
#scroller div.line {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 2.5px;
margin-top: 39px;
border-bottom: 3px solid;
border-color: #dd4b39;
}
#scroller div.ranges {
position: absolute;
width: 90%;
text-align:left;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 70px;
}
#scroller box.range {
position:absolute;
display: inline-block;
width: 30px;
height: 15px;
border-radius: 15%;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px #777777;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px #777777;
-ms-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px #777777;
-o-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px #777777;
box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px #777777;
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, #A8A8A8 0%, #BFBFBF 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #A8A8A8 0%, #BFBFBF 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #A8A8A8 0%, #BFBFBF 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #A8A8A8), color-stop(1, #BFBFBF));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #A8A8A8 0%, #BFBFBF 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #A8A8A8 0%, #BFBFBF 100%);
z-index: 2;
}
#scroller div.lrange {
position:absolute;
display: inline-block;
width: 15px;
height: 100px;
margin-top: -70px;
border-right: 1px dotted;
border-color: #dd4b39;
}
#scroller div.circle_small {
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 3px;
margin-top: 32.5px;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: #CC3524;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d14836, #dd4b39);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d14836, #dd4b39);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d14836, #dd4b39);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d14836, #dd4b39);
background: -linear-gradient(top, #d14836, #dd4b39);
}
#scroller div.circle_big {
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0px 3px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
margin-top: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: #CC3524;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d14836, #dd4b39);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d14836, #dd4b39);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d14836, #dd4b39);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d14836, #dd4b39);
background: -linear-gradient(top, #d14836, #dd4b39);
}
#scroller div.circle_label {
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px; 
padding: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for your problem. Just an unsolicited opinion. This kind of thing could end up being really annoying on a mobile (or a browser for that matter). I feel like I would expect the browser to scroll to the side (as it normally does), but instead, I'd be moving around the text in this box. Just my opinion. You may very well have a specific UX in mind that works, just thought I'd mention that.

Comment: what styles are associated with the divs created by jquery?

Comment: I'm trying to create a timeline. See EDIT

Comment: could it be something as simple as the fact that you've declared the width for #scroller to be 100% as opposed to say 1800px(arbitrary amount greater than 900px)?

Answer (score 0):

Might be late but still useful - i faced the same problem with scroll in mobile version of a website and found out that it's the position: absolute; that breaks it.

BUT! There is a solution - http://iscrolljs.com/ 
I found this very very helpful.

Basicly you just initialize the plugin on wrapper element without any changes to DOM and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

by adding this style into your div tag it will solve your problem.

```
<div style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;overflow-y: scroll;">
```